# Popup is coming with transparent in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, html

I am facing a problem to my displaying the popup. Popup is perfectly coming in all browsers, except Internet Explorer. Popup is coming with transparent in Internet Explorer. I don't know why? Here is my css:

```
.new_popup{
 position: fixed; 
 left: 149.5px; 
 top: 146px; 
 z-index: 100;  
 width: 496px; 
 display: none; 
 background:none; 
 -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100); 
 filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Anybody can help me?
Thanks
Tapas

Comment: Which version of IE do you use ?

Comment: What are you expecting instead of transparency?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on IE version, opacity doesn't have the same syntax:

```
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=10)"; /* IE 8 */
filter : alpha(opacity=10); /* IE < 8 */
opacity: 0.1; /* IE 9 */
```

What did you expect by setting:

```
background:none;
```

Comment: I want the popup with white background instead of transparency and contents and buttons inside the popup, don't want opacity or  transparent or like. Now it is showing with opacity/transparent and contents and buttons are not readable in IE only. I'm using IE 8. thanks - Tapas